# Existe uma lista exaustiva de numerais?

Tags: números

Ao pesquisar uma lista dos numerais ordinais, vê-se que 13º é *décimo terceiro*, mas, segundo o Priberam, há também *tredécimo*, *tércio-décimo* e *trezeno*. Semelhantemente, 14º também é *quatorzeno*/*catorzeno*. Dos fracionários, há *quaterno* e *quartano* para *quarto* (¼). Dos multiplicativos, há *víntuplo* para algo 20 vezes maior ou que se compõe de 20 coisas. Dos coletivos, há muitíssimos exemplos, como *díade* e *terno*.

Então pergunto: há alguma lista exaustiva de numerais?

Não sei se esta pergunta é válida.

Comment: Eu acho a pergunta válida, mesmo se fosse um [pedido de recursos](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/338) até hoje não se chegou a um consenso contra postar estas peguntas aqui no site principal embora noutros sites da rede estas perguntas não sejam aceites. Mas eu acho que a pergunta não é bem um pedido de recursos.

Comment: Caso não saibas o Priberam é um dicionário parcialmente "gerado" usado métodos [PLN](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processamento_de_linguagem_natural) nos casos mais obscuros os verbetes são derivados partindo de regras e [lemas de palavras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation). O facto de encontrares essas númerais  "raros" não indica que sejam usados mas que as regras da gramática permitiriam que fossem escritos assim. Não é o caso do díade e do terno que são lexicalizados e inventariados. Uma lista "completa" não existe, há listas dos numerais que não podem ser gerados por regras.

Comment: No caso do quatorzeno/cuatorzeno tens uma alteração no radical seguido do sufixo regular da regra gramatical do numeral. Se estão no priberam podes assumir que as regras de derivação usadas são válidas ou foram válidas em algum momento.

Comment: @bad_coder, não sabia disso: obrigado. Os exemplos que dei estão no Houaiss também, o qual data o uso das palavras, como *quatorzeno* que se usou em 1448. Outrossim concordo que não há lista completa, porém, uma exaustiva não intenta ser completa, ela intenta ser o mais completa possível.